# C++ how can I make includes global

Tags: c++

In c++ some header files are "global", you can always import it without needing to specify the path in the settings. Like "Windows.h" on windows. How can I make an sdk/api with header files "global"? So I can import it in every project without having to set it up again.

Comment: Search term: "c++ include path". You have to inform the compiler of the folder that contains the files of interest.

Comment: There's no "global" include files, there's just locations that are added to your include path by default, like `/usr/include` on POSIX, or various places in Windows. Don't be tempted to jam your own include files in here, these are intended to be used by *only* system software and the compiler(s) themselves.

Comment: Do you possible know the path on windows?

Comment: It'll show up in your build environment and/or the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: How you would do this likely depends on the IDE or compiler you are using and how you are building.  Since 2008 I use CMake to generate all projects at work. With CMake you  never manually type folders but you modify CMakeLists.txt files to script this.